# error con prettier en React

Tags: visual-studio, vscode

Estoy utilizando Visual Studio Code y mi código no compila, pero no es por algo en el código sino por algo diferente:

> Failed to compile
>
> Delete `CR`

Ésta es una captura de pantalla del error:

[image: Failed to compile. Delete CR]

¿Por qué puede suceder ese error? ¿Y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Uso el Visual Code, cómo configuro los terminadores??

Gracias por tu respuesta!

Comment: @Benito-B pon ese comentario como respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Estás mezclando [terminadores de línea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). Los sistemas basados en linux utilizan LF como final de línea, windows utiliza CR LF.

Ese error te está diciendo que tus líneas terminan en `crlf` y el *`cr`* sobra. Te recomiendo que utilices un editor de código que permita configurar los terminadores si quieres que tu código pase las reglas de prettier/sonar/lint.

En VSC la solución es muy sencilla, pues en la misma barra de abajo tienes un pequeño tag que indica si estás usando `CR` o `CRLF` y cambiarlo es tan sencillo como pinchar en él:
[image: Terminador de línea en uso actualmente en VSC]

Y seleccionar el nuevo formato que desees en la ventana que se abre:
[image: Cuadro de selección de nuevo terminador de línea]

---

Otra opción perfectamente válida es utilizar algún *formatter* que haga el cambio por ti. Por ejemplo, la extensión *Prettier* tiene esta función, además de otras cosas útiles!

Comment: La recomendación de Benito es muy buena, Prettier es un formateador que te va a ayudar a tener un código mas legible y quitarte problemas como el de los retornos de carro, si quieres ver como configurarlo, aquí van unos videos que te explican cómo configurarlo tanto a nivel global como de proyecto: https://www.lemoncode.tv/curso/prettier